# Socket Connection Stability

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, asynchronous

I have an async socket Server written in C#. Often, my users complain that they are disconnected from the without any reason. Other internet applications on the user's computer (MSN, SKYPE Etc.) appear to be well connected and therefore it does not seem to be an issue with their internet connection. Can anyone provide some information on how to make a connection between client and server rock solid (i mean prevent frequent disconnection) or where I can look for disconnection issues?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you expect us to work off of? Your question is too general. How can we guess all the possible variables for disconnection? Can you provide us with your code? What about reconnecting after disconnecting?

Comment: Do you have special protocol? Does it have some sort of ping/keep-alive mechanism? Can your server handle requests fast enough?

Answer (score 2):

Network Address Translators (aka "home routers", "wireless gateways", etc.) that share an ISP assigned IP address among multiple computers may be at play here. NATs keep a table of active connections (sometimes known as a "port mapping table") that keeps track of how to translate the ip:port pair for active TCP connections and observed UDP sessions. There are some brands of routers that are known to  clear the port mapping out of memory if it doesn't observe any traffic going over the TCP connection for some period of time. Apps like MSN Messenger and Skype mitigate this by periodically sending "keep alive" between client, server, and other persistent connections. These messages go in both directions.

You didn't give much information to go on, so the NAT problem is just one possibility out of many.

The best way to diagnose connectivity failures is to **invest heavily in logging** network messages (both on client and server), socket events, and all return values from the socket APIs.  That way, if a customer reports a problem, he can send you his logs - and hopefully you can fetch the corresponding server logs for comparison.  You can then diagnose where the disconnect originated from and/or what socket error reset the connection. There's a high probability something in your code is triggering the disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about TCP here. The socket library which the clients of your application use is pretty much the same as the one that they use to connect to Skype or MSN. Usually the reason for disconnect is that one of the parties closes the socket (e.g. after connection is idle for some time). Check the places in your code where you close your connections.